# Floated ______?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

Glazen cognac eyes followed the descent of a flower's petal as it floated _______ on the whispers of the breeze down from the brush of the thundercloud tree.

I'm in need of a word that illustrates a petals elegant fall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. . . . floated, lazily, on the whispers of the breeze . . . .

Comment: Thank you. This word matches the mood I am trying to set perfectly.